# Select resources that have no English label

Tags: sparql

I am trying to select all the resources that don't have an English label. The problem is that if I filter by another tag selector, it doesn't guarantee that the English label does not exist. The `FILTER NOT EXISTS` seems to work only for specific properties, but not in combination with a language selector.  How can I select resources which have no English label?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please edit your question to include queries you have tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search in a multilingual database for terms that have not been translated into a specific language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415515/search-in-a-multilingual-database-for-terms-that-have-not-been-translated-into-a)

Comment: I answered before I found that duplicate, sorry.  That question is looking for resources without a property value with language "de", but the answer carries over directly.  That answer uses `minus`, whereas mine here has used `filter not exists`.  Either will work, but there are some differences;  see [8.3 Relationship and differences between NOT EXISTS and MINUS](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-notexists-minus).

Answer (score 2):

For data like this, in which `:b` has no English labels,

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
:a :label "foo"@en .
:b :label "bar"@fr .
:c :label "baz"@en, "baz"@fr .
```

a query like this will return only `:b`, since it is the only resource with no English label:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
select * where { 
  ?x :label ?label .                           # find xs that do have a label
  filter not exists {                          # but for which no label in 
    ?x :label ?enLabel .                       # English exists
    filter(langMatches(lang(?enLabel),"en"))   
  }
}
```

The results, using Jena's `sparql` command line tools, are:

```
$ sparql --data data.n3 --query query.rq
-----------------
| x  | label    |
=================
| :b | "bar"@fr |
-----------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I meant