# Get all terms with at multilingual prefLabel

Tags: sparql

How do I query a thesaurus so that I get all concepts that have a translated prefLabel? Meaning to exclude all terms that only have an English prefLabel and only show the concepts with more than just an English prefLabel.

I found this and thought I could just reverse the concept, but that didn't really work.

[Search in a multilingual database for terms that have not been translated into a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415515/search-in-a-multilingual-database-for-terms-that-have-not-been-translated-into-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work, it does not check for the existence of an English label though :

```
SELECT ?term
WHERE 
{
  {
    SELECT ?term (COUNT(?label) AS ?pCount)
    WHERE 
      {?term <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> ?label}
    GROUP BY ?term
  }
  FILTER (?pCount > 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the English labels:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?label
WHERE {
   ?term skos:prefLabel ?label .
   FILTER (lang(?label) != "en")
}
```